# Разделить поступающую строку на буквы и цифры

Tags: python

Есть строка 'k3e10g88f13'
Нужно разделить её на буквы и цифры по отдельности. Единственное к чему я пришел это

```
x = 'k3e10g88f13'
word =[]
number = []
for i in x:
    if i.isalpha():
        word.append(i)
    else:
        number.append(i)
print(word, number,sep="\n")
```

Но тут у меня получается все цифры по отдельности формата 3, 1, 0, 8, 8, 1, 3, а мне нужно чтобы 3, 10, 88, 13.
Есть ли способы как то это проделать? Если есть, то какие? Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [регулярными выражениями](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

`[a-zA-Z]+` — одно и более повторений латинской буквы
`\d+` — одно и более повторений цифры

***Пример:***

```py
import re

x = 'k3e10g88f13'

chars = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', x)  # ['k', 'e', 'g', 'f']
nums = re.findall(r'\d+', x)         # ['3', '10', '88', '13']
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, лучше использовать регулярные выражения, но можно и ваш код "починить", добавив в него проверку, был ли предыдущий элемент такого же типа и в этом случае можно присоединять новый элемент к предыдущему. Ну и нужно не забыть обработать случай, когда предыдущего элемента ещё нет.

```
x = 'k3e10g88f13'
word =[]
number = []
for i in x:
    if i.isalpha():
        if not word or not last_isalpha:
            word.append(i)
        else:
            word[-1] += i
    else:
        if not number or last_isalpha:
            number.append(i)
        else:
            number[-1] += i
    last_isalpha = i.isalpha()
print(word, number,sep="\n")
```

Вывод:

```
['k', 'e', 'g', 'f']
['3', '10', '88', '13']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 'k3e10g88f13'
word = "".join(" " if el.isdigit() else el for el in x).split()
number = "".join(el if el.isdigit() else " " for el in x).split()

print(word)
print(number)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ха-ха, забавный способ, забавный ))